# Get a unique identifier of the current instance within typescript code for the multi-instance node js backend application

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, kubernetes, node-modules

We are using a node js application along with Kubernetes with auto-scaling.
My requirement is to log a few things wrt the current instance (pod, IP or anything unique for that instance).

Is there any way in the node js and typescript to get such identifiers in the backend application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname will contain the unique (per namespace) pod name.
So just get the current hostname of the backend and you have a unique identifier.

For example

```
const os = require("os");

const hostName = os.hostname();
```

Comment: As you mentioned per namespace pod name is unique. Is there any other unique identifier I can get?

Comment: If you have a replicaset or deployment to manage the pods it is highly unlikely that the pod name is not unique, since deployment and replicaset add their own suffixes to the pod name.